# Description labels disappear as I scroll on my UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**THE CODE:**

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSString *> *sections;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray<TableItem *> *> *items;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray<TableItem *> *sectionItems;

@end
```

...

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView *) tableView {
    return _items.count;
}

- (NSString *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger) section {
    NSLog(_sections[section]);
    return _sections[section];
}

-(NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _items[section].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath ];
    TableItem *item = _items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = item.title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = item.theDescription;
    return cell;
}
```

All appears as it should. When I scroll down and back up, the description labels have disappeared.

Some context:

**TableItem.h**

```
@interface TableItem : NSObject

@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSString *theDescription;

-(instancetype) initWithTitle: (NSString *) title theDescription: (NSString *) theDescription;

@end
```

It seems to be a problem with `dequeueReusableCell`. I know this has been asked before, but I checked all I could find and found no answer to my issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging *item*-s in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Perhaps, problem lies not in table view, but rather in your arrays

Comment: Ehh, wait! Why do you have *weak* properties in TableItem?

Comment: That fixed it ! Was a typo ! Could you please post an answer so I can reward you for helping me ? :D

Comment: I wish I could upvote you on top of accepting your answer, but not enough rep yet :/ sry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, the problem lies in TableItem properties. They are `weak`, which means actual strings can be freed and nilled at any moment.

So, by the time you scroll up and down, `title` and `theDescription` are already `nil`s.

Change your TableItem class:

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *theDescription;
```

Or, if you want to be sure that after assigning new value to its properties, these values can't be modified, use `copy`:

```
 @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *title;
 @property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *theDescription;
```

Comment: One thing that was weird though: the titles didn't disappear although they were also `weak`.

Comment: You're not guaranteed as to when exactly will object be freed, so it is possible that some object with reference count 0 is still available by weak reference for some time. You're just lucky :)

Comment: There is one more thing, that plays role here. Immutable strings (aka NSString objects) are **unique** across application and two different NSString objects created at different places with identical literals and exist at same time will be the same objects. That is, they will reference to same place in memory.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info !